# which matlab version should i use with windows7?

Tags: matlab

which matlab version should i use with windows7?

Answer (score 3):

Mathworks officially supports Windows 7 starting from version 2009a.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-92CVOW/

It's possible to run older versions as well with some tweaks. But it's always better to install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can only buy the latest version from Mathworks, I'd recommend you get the latest version!

Comment: matlab 7.6 is fine?

Comment: This is not true - if you are currently in maintenance for MathWorks products, they will provide you with old versions on request (at least going back quite a few versions, anyway).