# UAC issue with matlab on win 7

Tags: uac, matlab

I have the following problem using matlab on Windows 7.

When I double-click a .mat file matlab starts and loads the double-clicked file. Double-Clicking further .mat files opens them also in matlab. So far so good...

On the ohter hand, when I start matlab manually by clicking its Icon on the desktop, I get an "User Account Control" alert asking me if I "want to allow the following program from an unkown publisher to make changes to this computer".

The problem is that a double-click on a .mat file opens another instance of matlab. The running matlab is for some reason not recognized. Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: The simple solution is to open the file by hand from within the application. My guess is your using a version not designed to support Windows 7.  Here is a good question on that subject: http://superuser.com/questions/194806/which-matlab-version-should-i-use-with-windows7?rq=1

Comment: Of course this simple solution works. But I was asking for a solution to this annoying UAC issue. I forget to mention that I use matlab R2011b as all people in our department do without this kind of problem.

Comment: If other people are not having this problem then its a problem with your system's configuration.  Until you verify your configuration is correct, not much else we can suggest, if opening the file within the application isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: That's what I was asking for: What is the problem with my system configuration?

Comment: Thats a better question for your IT staff.  Of course I doubt this problem doesn't exist on your peer's computers also.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by right-click on the MATLAB icon, then selecting properties. Then I clicked on the Compatibility tab and selected the "Change settings for all users" button. In the window that opened, I unchecked "Run this program as an administrator."